# Где сохранять сырые данные MVP?

Tags: java, android, mvp, moxy

Для реализации MVP использую Moxy. Сегодня в первый раз использую данную либу, может уже из коробки есть решения возникших вопросов, но я не знаю о них. В целом вопрос больше в плане как это сделать не нарушая канонов MVP...

*Да, я знаю что в Moxy сохраняется ViewState при обращении из презентера `getViewState().showData(data);`*

---

Есть фрагмент, в котором запись редактируется(если она ранее была создана) или создается новая запись. *Если фрагмент открываем в режиме редактирования то в Arguments передаю ID записи который нужно редактировать.*

На самом деле у меня возникло 3 вопроса по этому кэйсу:

1. Когда презентер получает данные из репозитория(например, из сети), он должен его кэшировать в своем private поле? например, для последующей модификации при изменении из вьюшки (например, меняем текст в EditText)..
2. В случае если мы заходим в режиме редактирования, презентер подгружает информацию о редактируемой записе(например, **MyData**) и отправляет вьюшке для отображения. Теперь, пользователь редактирует запись(меняет текст в EditText, добавляет фото) - что должно происходить в этот момент? При любых изменениях мы должны эти изменения отправлять в презентер? Вот так:

   `presenter.addImage(imagePath);`

   `presenter.editTitle(newTitleText);`

   и что дальше презентер с этим должен делать? Модифицировать сохраненное в private поле из п.1 данные с помощью полученных в методах addImage и editTitle данными?
3. Какая будет логика в пунктах выше, если зашли в режиме создания новой записи?
4. Пункт №2, №3 интересны из-за пересоздания View при смене конфигурации.. Где же сохранять "сырые" данные?

Интересует как вы решаете такие кейсы! Как это сделать по умному не нарушая принципы паттерна MVP?

---

*оффтоп:
И еще, где-то читал, что, код типа этого: `presenter.addImage(imagePath);` неправильный, view не должно говорить презентуру что делать, а тут я говорю добавь фото. Или я просто неправильно понял ту мысль которую излагали?!*

Если все же я правильно понял, то я в ступоре..) Например, во вьюшке кликнул кнопку "добавить фото", презентер узнал об этом и отправил вьюшке команду "открой окно выбора", в этом окне я выбрал фото(из галереи), далее в onActivityResult получаю путь выбранной картинки, и по сути я должен с этой картинкой что то делать, или выполнить presenter.addImage(imagePath) или сообщить презентуру что, что то произошло и презентер должен это как-то обработать(а в этот момент пока я сообщаю презентеру и презентер как то начинает это обрабатывать где будет храниться картинка которая пришла в onActivityResult ? где то во вью? тогда получается вьюшка уже занимается не только вопросами UI). А как вообще на практике это решается? какой подход считается общепринятым? - вопрос для всех кто прочитает))

Comment: По оффтопу -- мысль поняли правильно. Вью не должна решать, что нужно делать, вью должна сообщать презентеру, что произошло какое-то событие, а презентер уже сам решает, что по этому событию нужно сделать.

Comment: В комент не влезло, дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Когда презентер получает данные из репозитория(например, из сети), он
>      должен его кэшировать в своем private поле?

Лучше кэшировать данные в репозитории, потому что репозиторий ответственен за управлением источниками данных(сети, базы, кеша). Здесь много разных подходов, я написал тот, который предлагает гугл.

> 2. и 3. Как работает презентер и вью при редактировании записи, при
>      добавлении новой записи?

Контракт (если хотите, можете оформить в виде интерфейса презентера) может быть такой:

```
public interface INotePresenter {

    void saveClicked();

    void imageChosen(File file);

    void editTitleClicked(String title);
}
```

Методы называются так, потому что как вы сами написали вьюха не должна говорить презентеру что делать, поэтому в названии метода сообщаем только то, что произошло какое-то событие.

Презентер можете создать через метод мокси

```
    @ProvidePresenter
    NotePresenter provideNotePresenter() {

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        int id = Objects.requireNonNull(bundle).getInt(NOTE_ID, 0);
        if( id == 0){
           return new NotePresenter();
        }else{
           return new NotePresenter(id)
        }
    }
```

В пустом конструкторе вы ничего не делаете. В конструкторе с айдишником делаете запрос в ваш репозиторий и устанавливаете `getViewState().showData(data);`

Остальные методы презентера проксируете(оборачиваете) в репозиторий. Можно только названия поменять на  `addImage(file)`, `addTitle(title)`

Уже в репозитории при вызове метода `getData(id)` вы кэшируете ваш объект mData, как глобальную переменную `private MyData mData = new MyData();` .

При вызове `imageChosen(file)` добавляете путь файла в кеше(объекте mData).

При вызове `editTitleClicked(String title)` обновляете тайтл в mData .

Метод `saveClicked()` можно сделать примерно таким:

```
 private void saveClicked(){
        if(mData.getId() == 0){
            mDb.insert(mData);  
        }else{
            mDb.update(mData);
        }
    }
```

Если у вашего айтема есть айдишник, то значит он был взят из бд и айтем надо обновить, если нет то значит это читсый кеш нового айтема и его надо вставить.

Comment: Спс. Получается при вызове метода презентера imageChosen(file), в презентера вызываю метод репозитория addPhoto(File f) - в этот момент если в репозитории mData == null, создаю его и добавляю фото. А как быть с изменением конфигурации UI(пересоздание), получается при каждом изменении кэша в репозитории, мне нужно вызывать в презентера getViewState().showData(dataCache); чтобы сохранять ui state?... Я, например, добавляю textChanges listener и при изменении текста отправляю его в презентер, не будет ли зацикливания? Можно конечно в showData проверять текущего значение..

Comment: ...После того как презентер получил изменения он выполняет getViewState().showData(dataCache);  для сохранения state. Как делаете Вы?

Comment: Да, все так. Забыл дописать, что при изменении кеша нужно вызывать метод `showData(dataCache)`, чтобы мокси обновил свой внутренний кеш и при повороте экрана был установлен новый кеш. Да, будет зацикливание. но editText сам обновляется, когда мы набираем в нем текст и не нужно на него потом сеттить те же данные, которые в нем и тогда проблем не будет. Если есть какие то проблемы с установлением правильного стейта можно разбить большой метод `showData(dataChanges)` на несколько методов, так будет легче управлять данными.

Answer (score 1):

1. Да. Не запрашивать же одни и те же данные на каждый чих
2. На мой взгляд тут зависит от того чего вы хотите. Вы можете на каждое изменение во вьюхе менять модель, а можете поменять модель 1 раз после нажатия на кнопку Save.
   Что бы вы не выбрали, вы должны сохранить именные данные в своем репозитории и вернуть новый объект сохранив его в приватное поле.
3. Мне кажется, что точно такая же, как в пункте 3.

Создали пустой объект, отобразили на вьюхе, его отредактировали и сохранили, вы сохранили в репозитории, который вернул новый объект в итоге, например с присвоенным ID.

4. Например, в .NET есть DataTable, где каждая строка хранит несколько состояний: `Original`, `Proposed` ,`Current`. Так вот, когда происходит какая-то модификация значение переносится в поле `Proposed` и Current. Когда значения комитятся, то все 3 состояния равны. Т.е как вариант, вы можете в свою модель добавить хранение промежуточного состояния.

Comment: Мысль понял, спасибо за ответ! Я пока не совсем изучил Moxy, но мне кажется что в каком то виде первый пункт там уже реализован т.к. Moxy презентер умеет восстанавливать состояние после пересоздания View - но наверное там сохраняется имутабле значение. Ответ достоин быть принятым, чуть позже.